# R command history: how to configure up-arrow to treat "multiline, brace-enclosed input" as one line?

Tags: r, navigation, console, readline, libreadline

This question is about configuring the R console to behave like a bash shell when it comes to navigating the command history.  It is somewhat related to the `?history`.  For brace-enclosed multi-lines, I'd like to configure the command history navigation of R to be similar to bash.

Presently when running R in an xterm under Linux, using the up-arrow to navigate the command history causes each previous line to be recalled one by one, even if a set of lines had been enclosed in braces.  This occurs, for example, when copy/pasting a multi-line function from a text editor into the R  console. Not so with bash.
 Here is an example of how bash functions in this regard:

In a bash shell within an xterm under Linux, after typing the following five lines...

```
a=1 
{
x=1
y=1
}
```

... the first press of the up-arrow will recall a single line reformulation of the brace-enclosed commands, like this ...

```
{ x=1; y=1; }
```

... and the second press will recall this ...

```
a=1
```

It seems that in R, the up-arrow navigates backwards one line at a time, regardless of encapsulation. Is there a way to configure R so that it's command history navigation functions like bash's?

Comment: In case you are an Emacs user (or would contemplate becoming one), it's prob. worth mentioning that ESS (Emacs Speaks Statistics) does just what you're asking for. And yes, it's *extremely* handy.

Comment: As does RStudio, if I understand the question correctly.

Comment: (OK, on re-reading your question, ESS actually does something a bit different (and nicer), recalling the entire pasted-in code block, whether or not it's enclosed in braces, or composed of several expressions, or whatever.)

Comment: @AriB.Friedman, are you sure? The RStudio server that we have implemented specifically lacks such functionality (and is consequently quite frustrating to use)

Comment: @RicardoSaporta Are you using the latest version?  I just tried it with RStudio Server (0.97.248) and it behaves as JoshO'Brien describes: recalls everything that was pasted in at a time with a single press of the uparrow.

Comment: The alternative is to find a text editor which supports "piping" to the console, which several do.

Comment: @AriB.Friedman, the Rstudio does it only when sourcing (from editor) multi line selection (beeing one function) into console. When typing directly into console it works line by line.

Comment: @PetrMatousu Not exactly.  Try typing directly into the console, but hit Shift-Enter instead of Enter.  Then when you arrow up it will pull up the whole expression at once.

Comment: @AriB.Friedman I see it now. Nice feature. But standard enter makes it same as any other linux R console - that I wanted to say.

Comment: @AriB.Friedman The same way as in Rstudio, but different keystrokes, in the linux terminal R session, C-V, C-J. Thanks to your comment.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [rlwrap](http://utopia.knoware.nl/~hlub/rlwrap/). I use it for other console programs and it works very well. You will need to prepend the R command with the rlwrap binary and then your history lines can be restored in a number of ways, including multi-line matching.

Comment: I tried installing this and running `rlwrap R` and didn't see anything different. Should I be doing smth else??

Comment: Check here http://utopia.knoware.nl/~hlub/rlwrap/rlwrap.html the --multi-line option.

Comment: @RobertKubrick Link is dead . Here is possibly? an updated one  http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/rlwrap.1.html

Comment: Any idea what the appropriate command-line to `rlwrap` would be for this? After reading the help it seems quite a challenge

Answer (score 1):

**Workaround for Linux/Unix**

Similarly as in Rstudio (thanks to *Ari B. Friedman* comment), where user in R console is using <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd> to bypass RETURN, you can start newline (in R terminal) without accepting newline command using <kbd>Ctrl-V</kbd><kbd>Ctrl-J</kbd>. This way the multi-line command will be accepted into history as one-liner with line-feeds instead of enters and you will even have the chance to edit it. You can even manage in your `.inputrc` file to have custom combination for this action.

I do not think direct reconfiguration of R is possible.

[Readline man page may help more.](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/readline.3.html)